# How to trigger IDEA debug task in between Gradle tasks?

Tags: docker, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, jvm

I run tests against my application in docker container.

The process of setting up a proper environment, then running tests, and then tearing everything down is automated thanks to [gradle-docker-compose-plugin](https://github.com/avast/gradle-docker-compose-plugin). The Gradle tasks execute in the following order:

```
build        <-- application build
composeBuild <-- create docker container with application
composeUp    <-- run container along with any other needed (e.g. database)
dockerComponentTest <-- my tests here!
composeDown
```

The problem is, due to automation of starting and stopping Docker containers, I can't attach a remote debug session to my application container in IJ IDEA.

Is there any approach to configure IDEA to run my test with remote debugger attached right after `composeUp` task but before `dockerComponentTest` task?

Right now the only approach I found is to run `dockerComponentTest` with debug, set breakpoint in test code and when, after the test is paused, attach to the application with another debug session. This is very inconvenient

P.S. For clarity, `dockerComponentTest` task is running on my host system along with Gradle. The test code is mostly sending HTTP requests to my application, which is running in Docker container. I have problems debugging **application** during testing, not the tests.

Comment: You may use a Docker Compose run target in your usual Application or Gradle run/debug configuration: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-targets.html#docker_compose

Comment: @y.bedrov Please can you provide more explanation